# MATLAB: Using fmincon inside a for loop

Tags: matlab

I am a novice in programming. I have about 100 data sets with 2 columns each. I want to fit col1 data as a power function of col2 data i.e.

```
variable(col1) = parameter1 x (variable(col2))^ parameter2

(say a (x^b)).
```

Now I would like to use the optimization function fmincon and get the value of the two parameters. I want to repeat this for all the 100 data sets and hence would like to include this fmincon within a for loop in which I call the data from each data set one at a time. I have tried my best and I am unable to get how to do this.

Any suggestions?

Comment: from comments to answer below it seems like this question has nothing to do with data sets and `for` loop. It is a question on how to use `fmincon`. As such, it is poorly phrased and I suggest it be closed or otherwise radically edited.

Answer (score 0):

Lets call the first column data set `k` `Xk` and the second one `Yk` (of size `m x 1`). If I understand your question correctly, then for each dataset `k` {`Xk`, `Yk`} you are looking for two *scalars* `ak` and `bk` such that

`Yk == ak * Xk.^bk` for all elements `1..m`

Since there are more equations/constraints than parameters (`m` equations with only two parameters) we seek a least-squares solution.

Taking `log` from both sides of the equation yields

```
log Yk == log ak + bk * log Xk
```

Defining new variables `YYk <- log(Yk)` and `XXk <- log(Xk)` we have a **linear** equations for `log ak` and `bk` -- this [can be solved easily](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mldivide.html) without `fmincon` or other optimization tools.
In fact, if we append the column vector `XXk` with another column of all ones (that is `XXk(:,2)=1`) we can write our system in matrix form

```
XXk * [ b ; log(ak)] == YYk
```

Now for some Matlab code:

```
N = 100; % number of data sets
a = zeros( 1, N ); % pre allocate room for all ak
b = zeros( 1, N ); % pre allocate room for all bk
for k = 1 : N
   % get the data here: Xk = ???, Yk = ???
   XXk = log( Xk );
   XXk(:,2) = 1; % add all ones column
   YYk = log( Yk );
   tmp = XXk \ YYk
   a(k) = exp( tmp(2) );
   b(k) = tmp( 1 );
end
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply Shai. I missed an important ingredient in my question. I wanted to use fmincon as I have some constraint for one of the scalars(parameters). Otherwise, I agree with the linearizing of the equation using log.

Comment: @user1957000 pity you failed to mention this tiny little detail in your question. But basically you have your `for` loop over the datasets `k` with `Xk` and `Yk` at each iteration - just plug in `fmincon` and be done with it.

Comment: thats where I am facing the problem..fmincon takes in a function as an input, but functions take some inputs and returns some outputs. But here in my case I am not having any inputs for the function, instead I have to find these values through optimization. I don't know how much clear am I, but it would be really helpful if you can give a snippet of code as you have given above..thanks in advance..

Comment: @user1957000 - so your question has nothing to do with the fact that you have ~100 datasets or `for` loop. You have a problem with `fmincon`. Have you read Matlab's doc on [how to write an objective function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/writing-objective-functions.html)? Read it. If you do have further questions phrase them clearly and concisely and do not waste other people's time guessing what you mean.